# After changing a preference (a setting), text showing settings doesn't update

Tags: android, android-preferences

I will try to explain a simple app scenario: My app goes right to a 'main view'. In this main view I have inserted a `TextView` which displays current settings created by way of the `PreferenceManager`. For simplicity sake, let's say I have a checkbox in my settings. When I first start my app - the `TextView` on my main view shows my checkbox setting correctly (true). Now I go to the settings menu, it pops-up, and then I change it to false. I go back to the main view and see no change. It still say's true even after I changed it to false. If I end the app and then re-start it - all is well and it shows my change.

Apparently the main view just stays in the background while I'm changing settings? How can I redraw or update the main view after I change settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go into your preferences your current activity should be paused and the resumed when you go back (see the lifecycle diagram on [lifecycle diagram on the android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles)). You should be able to trigger some kind of redraw from within onResume() I would think. That will allow the data on the page to repopulate. Some sort of invalidate() call would do it I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will begin to look into this now - I appreciate your time!

Comment: I'm a beginner so I hope this isn't too difficult for me - (I'll take more help and examples from others too)

Answer (score 23):

You could implement [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) in your main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    if (PREFKEY_OF_INTEREST.equals(key))
        updateSomethingInMainView();
}
```

and in  onCreate() call:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me. That onResume did the trick!