# How can I refresh view after a setting is changed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-settings

I have an app that displays distances and volumes. I have a SettingsFragment that allows me to choose the units for distance, mile or km, and for volume, gallon or liter. Changing between units works but not right away, I have to flip the phone or reset the app to see the changes. I want the setting change to be reflected right away on the main activity but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I have done some reseach and found a possible solution: The settings [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening) suggest that I should implement the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener interface to listen for changes. But this is implemented on PreferenceFragment and not on a different activity. This is a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633769/after-changing-a-preference-a-setting-text-showing-settings-doesnt-update).

I'm confused on what is the proper way to listen for the setting change on the main activity and how, when the change happens, I should refresh the view. Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the second link, using the onSharedPreferenceChangeListener() is what you need.  Setup the listener in the fragment and then notify the main activity with a call in your fragment:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).updateData(updatedData);
```

You will have to implement the public method updateData(...) in your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Observer is a good option for your problem.

Here has a sample. [OBSERVER](https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.